# log4net manifest definition mismatch

Tags: c#, silverlight, log4net

I'm getting this issue while running test client

**Could not load file or assembly 'log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1b44e1d426115821' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)**

I found many solutions like **adding both versions**, or **enable logging in registry** but nothing worked for me. I'm just stuck over here.

Anyone has any idea regarding this then please help me out. Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect you have a reference mismatch between two different assemblies with one expecting version 1.2.10.0 of log4net and another some other version. One version of the log4net assembly is copied to your output directory when your solution is built and then when your program is launched the .exe loader is then complaining because it isn't able to load the version of particular assembly (or .exe) is expecting. Upgrading / downgrading your assemblies to use the same version of log4net should solve the problem.

Comment: I'm using same version but still getting the error.

Comment: Have you done a full clean of the solution, including removing all obsolete assemblies from the packages folder (assuming you're using nuget). Have you checked the project files themselves to double check what your assemblies are referencing? Are your project files copying assemblies around in the post build event to the output folder?

Comment: yeah I've done full clean of the solution. No I'm not using nuget so no any obsolete assembly in solution. 
yes I already have double checked all references. -_-

Comment: Removing all obsolete assemblies and deleting all bins and obj folders from project resolved my issue.
Thanks Jack.